# TikZ Mindmap: Distances between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

How do I set the distance between nodes *edges* instead of node *centers* with the center still being the anchor?

Here the distances between edges is different (because of the different sizes of the child nodes):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\tikzset{
    every node/.append style={concept, rectangle, minimum size=0cm, inner sep=2mm, text width=, minimum size=0cm}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,text=white,fill=white]
\path node {O} [clockwise from=45, level 1/.append style={sibling angle=45} ]
child { node[align=center] {AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA} }
child { node {BBB} };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I ask why exactly you want to use the `mindmap` style? It is just that if you want to change so many aspects of it, it seems to be more hindrance than help and I wonder whether it would not just be much easier to create your diagram without it.

Comment: @cfr: I am not sure how else to do it - except setting all nodes completely manually and connecting them.

Comment: @Make42 Tikz can be more than just manual. It just depends on what you need to do.

Comment: The `chains` library might be helpful. It is hard to know for sure without knowing a bit more about the overall diagram you are trying to produce. But based on your queries so far, I'd guess that `chains` would be a lot easier than `mindmap`.

Comment: @cfr: No, we are definitely talking about mindmaps here. This was just for demonstration (MWE) - though I change it.

Comment: Yes, but a mind-map may not be most easily drawn using the `mindmap` style if you do not want it to look much like the mind-maps that style is designed to produce ;).

Answer (score 3):

There is no ready-made solution for drawing 'regular' mind-maps using TikZ, as far as I am aware. The `mindmap` style provided by the `mindmaps` library draws nice looking diagrams *if you want a map which looks like that* but the style is somewhat eccentric and rather inefficient. (It does not make very good use of space because circular nodes do not make for a compact map.)

The upshot is that the fact that you want to draw a mind-map does not necessarily make `mindmaps` a good choice. A `mindmap` in that sense is intended to have a particular look and feel and is intended to be structured as a `tree` with a cyclical growth function. If you want a different-looking mind-map (whether less eccentric or merely eccentric in a different way), other options may be better.

There are other non-manual ways of placing nodes in TikZ. Nodes can be placed on grids, in a `matrix of nodes`, on a `chain`, in a `tree` (a `mindmap` assumes the nodes are part of a `tree` and builds on top of that, but there are other ways of using a `tree`). You can also use polar rather than Cartesian, coordinates, for example (especially good for placing nodes around a central root or point). And there are other possibilities besides.

Here's a small example using the `chains` library which sets up one chain going north east from the root and a branch going south west.

I'm not sure why you want to avoid specifying `anchor` as anything other than `center` given that you seem to want to anchor the nodes using points on their borders rather than their centres. Isn't this precisely the kind of case which alternative anchors are made for?

Of course, this particular case could more easily be drawn as a single, non-branching chain. But I assume you will have other first-level children to place relative to the root node and so will want all chains/branches to begin from that point. Hence I've set it up that way.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every on chain/.append style={inner sep=2mm, fill, text=white, join={by {line width=1mm, shorten >=-1mm, shorten <=-1mm }}}]
    {[start chain=main going {at=(\tikzchainprevious), shift=(45:1), anchor=south west}]
      \node [on chain] {O};
      {[start branch=first going {at=(\tikzchainprevious), shift=(-135:1), anchor=north east}]
        \node [on chain] {BBB};
      }
      \node [on chain, align=center] {AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: chained nodes]

You can then develop this in various ways. For example

[image: developing chains]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes,shadows}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every on chain/.append style={inner sep=2mm, inner color=black, outer color=black!90, draw, thick, drop shadow, rounded corners, text=white, join={by {line width=1mm, shorten >=-1mm, shorten <=-1mm }}}]
    {[start chain=main going {at=(\tikzchainprevious.north east), shift=(45:1), anchor=south west}]
      \node [on chain] {O};
      {[start branch=first going {at=(\tikzchainprevious.south west), shift=(-135:1), anchor=north east}]
        \node [on chain] {BBB};
      }
      {[start branch=second going {at=(\tikzchainprevious.north west), shift=(135:1), anchor=south east}]
        \node [on chain] {Orangutans};
        \node [on chain] {Aardvarks};
      }
      \node [on chain, align=center] {AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA};
      \node [continue chain=going below, on chain, anchor=north] {Bees};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```